# Getting React useEffect to display updated variable after contract call?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, blockchain, ethereum, use-effect

I'm working on a blockchain application using react function components. The application would allow people to deposit ERC20 tokens.

I've been trying for the last few days to get the useEffect hook to watch for state changes coming in from the blockchain and display them once they occur, but have not had success.

I know this fundamentally working with my useEffect hook as the application updates its displayed state when an account is loaded from a wallet/on an account state variable change, which it's watching for. However, because I believe there is a delay when it's making a contract call, it seems to run through and update itself before that new updated information comes from the blockchain.

I'm trying to get it so that when the user deposits their token, the app calls the smart contract to deposit using await, then once the token is deposited it calls for the new balance and sets the state, this is then displayed in the app without having to refresh the page.

I tried several methods including promises, having a shorterm loop run until the data is updated (which just spammed my app with calls), etc.

Any advice or links to guides that cover updating state using useEffect, especially for blockchain calls, would be much appreciated!

```
function App() {
  
  const [tether, setTether] = React.useState([undefined]);
  const [tetherAddress, setTetherAddress] = React.useState("");
  
  const [tetherBalance, setTetherBalance] = React.useState("0");
  
  const [amountDeposited, setAmountDeposited] = React.useState("0");
  
  window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
```

Skipping the load web 3 & contract instances for brevity...

```
  useEffect(() => {

    const init = async () => {

        //Load our staking state and other account data

        if (account !== undefined){
          let tetherBalance = await tether.methods.balanceOf(account).call().then()
          setTetherBalance(tetherBalance.toString())
         
          let amountDeposited = await chadsVault.methods.amountDeposited(account).call();
          setAmountDeposited(amountDeposited.toString());

        } 
        
    }
    init();
  }, [account, tetherBalance, amountDeposited]);
```

Comment: As an update, I'm attempting a work around where I use a timeout to wait for the new data so that it can update state. It works - but this doesn't take into account the varying times it takes for a blockchain tx to be mined. 

I'm not sure how to configure this to wait for the transaction to complete. 

'

Comment: Code: 

`async function handleAsync() {
    
    setTimeout( async () => {

  
      
      let amountDeposited = await chadsVault.methods.amountDeposited(account).call()
      setAmountDeposited(amountDeposited.toString());

       }, 30000);
  }`